# searching from database

Tags: java, sql

```
private void btgetinvActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    if(tf_rmid.getText().length()==11){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"REMITTANCE ID IS VALID!");
        try {
                DBUtil util = new DBUtil();
                Connection con = util.getConnection();
                Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select bk_det.rm_id from bk_det inner join bk_rep on bk_det.rm_id = bk_rep.rm_id WHERE rm_id = ?");
                String rm = tf_rmid.getText().trim();          
                stmt.setString(1, ""+(rm));
                while(rs.next()){
                   int i = rs.getString("RM ID");
                   String fn = rs.getString("First Name");
                   String ln = rs.getString("Last Name");
                   String title = rs.getString("Title");
                   String city = rs.getString("City");
                   txtFirstName.setText(fn);
                   txtLastName.setText(ln);
                   txtTitle.setText(title);
                   txtCity.setText(city);
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
                Logger.getLogger(Demo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
    }else{
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"PLEASE ENTER VALID REMITTANCE ID!");
    }
```

}

I am trying to search values from my database using the select statement but when i am trying to get the value for ? for the where option i am getting error i think its a syntax mistake can ny one please help???

Answer (score 1):

Execute with this,

```
select bk_det.rm_id from bk_det inner join bk_rep 
on bk_det.rm_id = bk_rep.rm_id WHERE bk_det.rm_id = ?
```

Probably you are missing table name in where clause

Comment: ya thank you i have made the changes but how can i attach the values to the ? from the textfield. i have done it but it is showing some error of cannot find symbol

Answer (score 1):

It appears a bit odd that you are setting the parameter to the Statement AFTER you execute the query.

Also

int i = rs.getString("RM ID");

this does not compile (if rs is a java.sql.ResultSet instance)

Answer (score 1):

Use a prepared Statement:

```
    String query = "select bk_det.rm_id from bk_det inner join bk_rep on bk_det.rm_id = bk_rep.rm_id WHERE rm_id = ?";
    try {
        PreparedStatement preps = con.prepareStatement(query);
        preps.setString(1, ""+(rm));
        preps.execute();
        ...
```